# How to change the order of first/last name in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I have a question on changing the order of first/last names of authors using `biblatex`. For example, the `.bib` file contains one entry as:

```
@incollection{Liu:2001vx, <br>
author = {Liu, Jane and West, Mike}, <br>
title = {{Combined parameter and state estimation in simulation-based filtering}},<br>
booktitle = {Sequential Monte Carlo methods in practice},<br>
year = {2001},<br>
editor = {Doucet, Arnaud and de Freitas, Nando and Gordon, Neil},<br>
pages = {197--224},<br>
publisher = {Springer}<br>
}
```

I want the compiled output of author names to be in the form of First von Last, Jr. How to make `biblatex` to output the author names in the desired order. For example, the West, Mike is in the `.bib` file, I want the name to be printed as Mike West.

I appreciate for your kind and prompt help.

Comment: This depends on the bibliography style. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076/510 and there at the section "Bibliography – order of first names and last names".

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I still have questions. I tried to add <br>\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{BMS}in my .tex file

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I still have questions. I tried to add <br>\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}<br>

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}<br>
\bibliography{BMS}<br> in my .tex file. Then, use pdflatex to compile, and I got an error message "! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \DeclareNameAlias
                     {sortname}{first-last}"<br> Could yu help me more on making DeclareNameAlias to work with bibliographystyle. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I still have questions. I tried to add `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last} \bibliographystyle{unsrt} \bibliography{BMS}` in my .tex file. Then, use pdflatex to compile, and I got an error message "! Undefined control sequence. `l.3 \DeclareNameAlias {sortname}{first-last}"` Could yu help me more on making DeclareNameAlias to work with bibliographystyle? Thank you.

Comment: @JunLiu The `first-last` formatting directive was added to biblatex 1.0. If you're using an earlier version, you should upgrade.