# Defining rules for maxbibnames in biblatex authoryear

Tags: biblatex, authoryear

I would like to tweak the `authoryear` style in `biblatex`. Specifically, I would like to define separate cases for `maxbibnames`.
The behavior I am looking for is:

1. If the publication has up to 8 authors, I want to cite all authors in the bibliography
2. If the publication has more than 8 authors, I want to cite the first 7 authors + et. al.

Furthermore, I need to change the order of the author's last and first names between the first and subsequent authors.

1. first author: Last name, first name
2. all subsequent authors: first name, last name

I have tried defining `maxbibnames=7`. This will list all authors in publications with up to 7 authors and list the first author + et. al. in publications with more than 7 authors.
Lets say the `.bib` file `my_ref.bib` looks like this:

```
@Article{Danecek2011,
  author   = {Danecek, Petr and Auton, Adam and Abecasis, Goncalo and Albers, Cornelis A. and Banks, Eric and DePristo, Mark A. and Handsaker, Robert E. and Lunter, Gerton and Marth, Gabor T. and Sherry, Stephen T. and McVean, Gilean and Durbin, Richard and 1000 Genomes Project Analysis Group},
  title    = {{The variant call format and VCFtools}},
  journal  = {Bioinformatics},
  year     = {2011},
  volume   = {27},
  number   = {15},
  pages    = {2156-2158},
  doi      = {10.1093/bioinformatics/btr330},
}
```

In a nutshell my code looks like this:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.6cm, right=2.9cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[sorting=nyt, citestyle = authoryear,  bibstyle = authoryear, giveninits=true, isbn = false, url = false, eprint = false, doi = false, dashed = false, uniquelist = minyear, maxcitenames = 2, maxbibnames = 7, backend = biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my_ref.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Danecek2011}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is:

> Danecek, P. et al. (2011): "The variant call format and VCFtools". In: *Bioinformatics* 27.15, pp. 2156-2158.

I would like to receive something like:

> Danecek, P., A. Auton, G. Abercasis, C. A. Cornelius, E. Banks, M. A. DePristo, R. E. Handsaker et al. (2011): "The variant call format and VCFtools". In: *Bioinformatics* 27.15, pp. 2156-2158.

Comment: For displaying at least 7 authors you need `minbibnames` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76240)

Comment: Defining `minbibnames = 7 ` and `maxbibnames = 8` gives the desired behavior without changing the last name and first name order. Thank you!

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but the `1000 Genomes Project Analysis Group` in the author field should be protected with additional curly braces: `{1000 Genomes Project Analysis Group}`. Otherwise Biber will try to parse it into given and family name. Also `title = {{The variant call format and VCFtools}},` would be better as `title = {The Variant Call Format and {VCFtools}},`.

Answer (score 0):

Two separate pieces of code solve my problem:
`\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family}` will change the order of first and last names [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73217/how-to-change-the-order-of-first-last-name-in-biblatex) and `minbibnames = 7` together with `maxbibnames = 8`

Comment: `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family}` is the default in your style, so it shouldn't be needed.